# Moving from Ionic 1 to ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Trying to port my App from Ionic 1 to Ionic 2, just got a few queries:

1. How can I setup Push/Pop pages links so they work when they click on an image, rather than a button?
2. Do background images still work the same as Ionic 1, doesn't seem to work in Ionic 2?
3. What is the correct way to paste my entire CSS from my Ionic app, rather than seperate it into bits in Ionic 2 to compile the scss files?
4. How can I comment out Typescript? I have tried /* and
5. How would my list of products currently stored in factories.js be used and imported in Ionic 2? jsfiddle(dot)net/vgthumsm/
6. Where does controller code and then the JS functions underneath get pasted into the .ts file? jsfiddle(dot)net/qov7bh0w/

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to push (or pop) a page on the NavController stack, you would need to respond to some event to do it in code AFAIK.
2. Background images should work fine using CSS.
3. `app/theme/app.core.scss` is your best bet
4. Comments work the same as javascript comments.

`// this line is commented
/* commented out
stuff
on several lines */`